# ZOHO Creator: How do I add uploaded images from and Image Field to a Page

Tags: image, file-upload, zoho, imagefield

It seems like, when I walkthrough each record and display the image link, it links to some type of default path that looks like a broken link.

I looked it up over and over but there is nothing that I can see that works.

Does anyone know how to make an uploaded image show up on a page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to extract image name from field.

You can use for example this function :

```
string extractFileName(string imgField)
{
    path = input.imgField.getSuffix("src");
    path = path.getSuffix("\"").getPrefix("\"");
    pos = path.lastIndexOf("/");
    path = path.subString((pos  +  1)).trim();
    return path;
}
```

To embed your image into html you have to publish your report related to your form.
Your published url should look like this:

https://creator.zohopublic.com/<user>/<app>/view-perma/<Report_Name>/<privatelink>

Link to your image is:

https://creator.zohopublic.com/<user>/<app>/<Report_Name>/<Record_ID>/Image/image-download/<privatelink>/<FileName>